# Possible column limit in SSRS Matrix report being uploaded to Report Manager in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting this error :

> SQL Server Reporting Services
>
> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

I am attempting to upload my SSRS Matrix report to Report Manager. The report has a lot of columns (109 row columns followed by the variable number of column columns).

After trial and error, I discovered that when I only have 107 row columns I can upload successfully.

Can anybody explain why this is happening? Is there a limit of 107 columns?

Comment: You may experience problems with complex reports due to the resource limitations on the server.  I don't believe there is a max number of columns that a matrix can handle.  However, you might consider some different approaches to your report - 100+ columns is right about unusable.  I would suggest working with column groupings to simplify the view, consider using drill through reports rather than have it all in one and perhaps use visualizations (sparklines) to replace many of the columns.  Avoid horizontal scrolling and don't let the users convince you that they need 100 column lookup table.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need all the columns as it is also being exported as a .csv file for our clients to import into SAS for their manipulations. The matrix report is for our verification. I can do it with a normal table report but there are many more lines depending on the number of vertical columns.

Comment: If the goal is a cvs for the purposes of a data extract, this would be more easily accomplished through ssis, which is intended for data movement. Is that a possibility?

Comment: I have a separate step that creates a table in our DW after extracting all the necessary columns from various other tables. Then I have a step that reads this table to write out the csv file. I have a further step which is the matrix report which also reads the table created to produce the report for our verification. Thanks for your suggestion.